# `Graphics.Blit` into a render texture using a custom material outputs black

Tags: unity, c#, asset-management, rendertexture

### Context

I am writing a `ScriptableImporter` for a specialised image format (the specifics are not relevant). To do so, I need to semi-procedurally generate a `Texture2D`. My idea was to create a `RenderTexture` at import time, and call `Graphics.Blit(source, destination, material)` on it using a material whose shader that does the procedural part of the job.

*I acknowledge this might be a bit of an XY problem*, so I will also accept an answer that generally allows me to render a shader to a texture of a specified size, which is the actual use case.

I am using Unity 2022.2.19 and Universal Render Pipeline 14.0.7.

### The problem

However, I don't seem to be able to use this technique. I created a trivial shader that simply outputs white everywhere, and called `Blit` with it, yet the texture is still completely black.

### The code

#### Test shader

```
Shader "Hidden/My Cool Shader"
{
    Properties
    {
        _MainTex("InputTex", 2D) = "white" {}
     }

     SubShader
     {
        Blend One Zero

        Pass
        {
            Name "Blit"

            CGPROGRAM
            #pragma vertex vert
            #pragma fragment frag
            #pragma target 3.0

            sampler2D _MainTex;
            
            struct appdata {
                float4 uv0: TEXCOORD0;
            };
            
            struct v2f {
                float4 uv0: TEXCOORD0;
            };
            
            v2f vert(appdata vertex) {
                v2f fragment;
                fragment.uv0 = vertex.uv0;
                return fragment;
            }

            float4 frag(v2f IN) : SV_Target
            {
                return float4(1,1,1,1);
            }
            ENDCG
        }
    }
}
```

#### Double-buffered helper

This is so I can render multiple times to the "same" texture, as I might

```csharp
internal struct DoubleBufferedRenderTexture : IDisposable
{
    private RenderTexture _a;

    private RenderTexture _b;


    public DoubleBufferedRenderTexture(CustomRenderTexture source)
    {
        _a = source;
        _b = Object.Instantiate(source);
    }


    public void Blit(Material material)
    {
        Graphics.Blit(_a, _b, material);
        (_a, _b) = (_b, _a);
    }


    public RenderTexture Consume()
    {
        var result = _a;
        _a = null;
        return result;
    }


    public void Dispose()
    {
        Object.DestroyImmediate(_a);
        Object.DestroyImmediate(_b);
    }
}
```

#### The Blitting

```csharp
var canvas = new DoubleBufferedRenderTexture(new RenderTexture(64, 64, GraphicsFormat.R32G32B32A32_SFloat, GraphicsFormat.None));
var brush = new Material(Shader.Find("Hidden/My Cool Shader"));

// Here I would set up the material properties when using an actual shader.

canvas.Blit(brush);
ctx.AddObjectToAsset("test", canvas.Consume());
canvas.Dispose();
```

### What I've tried

- Using a `CommandBuffer` instead of directly using `Graphics.Blit`;
- Copying the `RenderTexture` to a plain `Texture2D` to save in the asset;
- Skipping the double-buffering helper and ensure I'm just calling `Blit` once in a single texture.